# Change network values from sysctl.conf

Tags: linux, networking, systemd, sysctl

Can I change the value of those parameters (`spoofprotect`, `syncookies`, `dynaddr_hack`, `notimestamps`, `nobroadcasticmpecho`, `ip_forward`) from `sysctl.conf` file in `systemd`?

Comment: What do you mean "from sysctl.conf"? Does it mean change those value by editing `sysctl.conf` file?

Comment: in system based on `initd`, we can change those values in `/etc/network/options`. But for systems based on `systemd`, this file no longer exist. And this is my question , how can we modify those values ? can we do that from `sysctl.conf` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](http://leaf.sourceforge.net/doc/buci-network.html) link, I see that, these values can be edited.

```
ip_forward=no
ipv6_forward=no
spoofprotect=yes
syncookies=no
```

The above variables can now be set in `/etc/sysctl.conf` which is acceseble via the System configuration menu, System variables.

From [this](https://superuser.com/a/306179/252686) answer, I see changing `net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts` is not going to change anything.

For timestamp, I believe you refer to the system variable `net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps`. As per [this](https://ticketing.nforce.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/40/0/sysctl-settings-which-can-have-a-negative-affect-on-the-network-speed) link, it is suggested to leave it turned on unless if you live on an extremely slow connection such as a 56 kbps modem connection to the internet.